# How to use the same message returned from Auth0 response?

Tags: reactjs, auth0, auth0-lock

I want to show the same message coming from Auth0 response without customizing it manually. Like, For Invalid_grant, the response from Auth is

`{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Wrong email or password."}`

But it is displaying - **"WE'RE SORRY, SOMETHING WENT WRONG WHEN ATTEMPTING TO LOG IN.".**

I want to show the same message as in "error_description".